# Jumping to another Scene without Playing the Sounds AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, scene

I am having a critical issue with sounds in Flash CS6 AS3 , I will make my question very simple.

For Example:

I have 3 Scenes in the Project

"Scene 1"
"Scene 2"
"Scene 3"

I have a Button in "Scene 1" which should take me to "Scene 3" when Clicked.

the Problem is: all Sounds within MovieClips in "Scene 2" Automatically Starts , I am using this code:

```
btnGoS3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK , btnGoS3CH);

function btnGoS3CH (e:MouseEvent) :void {

gotoAndStop(1,"Scene 3");

}
```

I Thought that the above code should take me to "Scene 3" without any problems I don't know why Sounds from "Scene 2" starts while I am not going to "Scene 2" at all

Please provide a simple and clear solution , take in consideration that I have a tremendous amount of movieclips in my real project , so stoping the sound of each movieclip might not be good for me as I have MovieClip inside MovieClip etc.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try some of the suggestions given here maybe: http://stv.whtly.com/2009/01/21/as3-stop-all-sounds-from-playing/

Comment: Well thanks , but I have already tried SoundMixer.stopAll(); first of all sounds are in MovieClips in Scene 2 , so why they starts? and if I could in someway stop all the sounds , don't forget I have other MovieClips and other sounds with in Scene 3 , So Stoping all Sounds IS NOT THE SOLUTION , I still cannot believe why Sounds from Scene 2 starts while I am not actually going there ...

Comment: is converting your scenes to movieclips an option?

Comment: Thanks for you question, What do you mean , I already have a large number of MovieClips , I am developing a game where each scene is a level and each level has a lot of movieClips a lot and a lot of sounds buttons etc. so now I made it simple and created a new empty project with 3 scenes , and had a button in scene 1 where should take me to Scene 3 when Clicked and I had a movieClip which contains a sound in Scene 2 , So when I publish and Click that button it simply takes me to Scene 3 however the sound from Scene 2 starts !, and this what I don't want